# Error to upload my app: App Sore Connect Operation Error

Tags: app-store, xcode10

I tried to upload my new app to App Store using Xcode 10, It's showing this error

[image]

Just use:

```
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'HTHorizontalSelectionList', '~> 0.7.4'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
```

What is "**Aspera transport**"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's too late or not, but I came across this issue this past weekend, it looks like Xcode 10 and application Loader version 3.7 are not working when trying to publish your app on itunes connect.

The solution: I found out that if you use application loader v3.6 the app will be successfully uploaded to itunes connect, that version of application loader belongs to the previous version of Xcode which is version 8. Application loader must be present in the application folder of that version of Xcode.